# htaccess and SSL proxy

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, proxy

My new host is using SSL with proxy, on my old hosts I could use this rules in htaccess:

```
#old host
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder

SSLOptions +StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "www.website.eu"
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.website.eu/folder
```

But this does not work on my new host with SSL proxy I tried the following but no luck:

```
#new host
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-SSLproxy} !Yes
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.website.eu/folder
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: off topic. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of the ErrorDocument line:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I don't think it works if you are using Apache authentication though, the rewrite happens after the auth.